# SQL Server create database dynamically and use the database in the script

Tags: sql-server

I have a script that can be represented by the following:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseNamePart VARCHAR(50) = 'Part1'
DECLARE @DataBaseName VARCHAR(70) = 'MyDataBase_' + @DatabaseNamePart

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE [name] = @DataBaseName) BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(150) = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @DataBaseName
    EXECUTE (@SqlQuery)     
END

DECLARE @UseDatabase NVARCHAR(150) = 'USE ' + @DataBaseName
EXECUTE ( @UseDatabase )

/**************************************************************************/
/*                           CREATE TABLES                                */
/**************************************************************************/

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE [name]='MyTable' AND xtype='U') BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE MyTable (
        [id] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [Name] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    )
END
```

The problem is when I create the table after it's not created in the new database but in whatever database I am currently on.

Any idea on how to use a database that you just created and don't know the name in advance?

Comment: The session reverts back to the original database context after the dynamic SQL executes. If you need to create the database and objects in the same batch, you'll need to execute those dynamically and include a USE in the script. It would be a lot easier to execute the `CREATE DATABASE` in a different batch.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid :(

Comment: How are you executing this script? Why do you not want to make multiple calls to the database?

Comment: The script is in a store procedure to avoid making multiple calls to the server. The reason behind this is, the application calling is a 3 tiers app on a bad connection and each call to the server takes anywhere from 500ms to 800ms. For now it's not possible change this for many reason so I am ask to reduce the call to the server to the minimum possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DatabaseNamePart VARCHAR(50) = 'Part1'
DECLARE @DataBaseName VARCHAR(70) = 'MyDataBase_' + @DatabaseNamePart

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE [name] = @DataBaseName) BEGIN
    DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(150) = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @DataBaseName
    EXECUTE (@SqlQuery)     
END



-- code edited - declaring a new variable and setting the dbname

Declare @newDBName VARCHAR(30)

SET @DBName = @DataBaseName

exec('USE '+ @DBName)

-- code edited


--Create tables query

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE [name]='MyTable' AND xtype='U') BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE MyTable (
        [id] INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
        [Name] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    )
END
```

Comment: The `GO` statement is only implemented by SQL Server utilities, so if this code is being executed using, e.g., ADO.NET, that will not work. See the remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 "GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor."

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem is handling this server side.

- You would use a connection string pointing to **master** database. This connection string will be used to create the new db (let's call it ***Fruits***)
- You would use another connection string pointing to the newly created db (i.e. a connection string pointing to e.g. Fruits)

Use the following as a guiding example:

1. You call the method below to create the Database:

```cs
public async Task CreateDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        var query = @"CREATE DATABASE [Xy] CONTAINMENT = NONE ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'Xy', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Xy.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
        LOG ON 
        ( NAME = N'Xy_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Xy_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
        WITH LEDGER = OFF".Replace("Xy", databaseName);
        
        try
        {
            var connection = _databaseConnector.GetSqlConnectionMasterDatabase();
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Db failure for {@Operation}! {@Exception}", nameof(CreateDatabase), ex);
        }
    }
```

2. You call the needed operation on the db that you just created (e.g the Fruits db)

```cs
public async Task CreateSomeTable(string databaseName)
    {
        const string query = "CREATE TABLE Pineapple (PineappleID BIGINT NOT NULL, DateOfBirth datetime2 null)";

        try
        {
            var connection = _databaseConnector.GetSqlConnectionCustomDatabase(databaseName);
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Db failure for {@Operation}! {@Exception}", nameof(CreateSomeTable), ex);
        }
    }
```

3. How do you define a custom connection i.e. pointing to a custom database ? See below

```cs
 public SqlConnection GetSqlConnectionCustomDatabase(string customDatabase)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringForMasterDatabase.Replace("master", customDatabase));
    }
```

4. Example of calling code:
   (where **_myRepository** provides the implementations above)

```cs
const string dbName = "Fruits";
await _myRepository.CreateDatabase(dbName);
await _myRepository.CreateSomeTable(dbName);
```